# value error. model field must be an instance django

Tags: python, django

I want to save a list of the relational objects using IDs but unfortunately, I'm getting an error from Django which I attached below.

error:

```
Cannot assign "[<Tag: Tag object (189)>, <Tag: Tag object (190)>]": 
"PackageRoom.tag" must be a "Tag" instance.
```

models.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    singleline = models.ManyToManyField(Singleline)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tags'



class PackageRoom(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.PROTECT) 

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'package_rooms'
```

serializers.py

```
class PackageRoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tag = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Tag.objects.all(), many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = PackageRoom
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'tag']
```

views.py

```
serializer = PackageRoomSerializer(data=request.data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
serializer.save()
```

JSON object which is sent from Frontend:

```
{
   "name": "example room", 
   "description": "lorem lipsum",
   "tag": [189, 190]
}
```

Comment: You have got the wrong kind of relationship between those models for what you want. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: What happens if replace primarykeyrelated serializers paramter ```queryset=Tag.objects.all()``` to```read_only=True```

Comment: @Sumithran then the error is `null value in column "tag_id" of relation "package_rooms" violates not-null constraint`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I don't want many to many relation but one to many

Comment: Then you have the FK on the incorrect side, `Tag` should have the fk to `PackageRoom` (not the other way). If that's not what you want either why do you try to create a single `PackageRoom` with _multiple_ `Tag` instances?